# Tentativeness vs Hedging

Tags: academic-writing

I am currently studying for an exam about academic writing and I have some issues grasping the difference between hedging and tentativeness.

I know for a fact that there must be a difference because my professor marked it in a text of mine.

What I can say is that tentativeness aims to avoid making false claims, thus texts written tentatively are more restrained.

Hedging on the other hand is a politeness tool that also happens to express hesitation.

But as of now, I still cannot see a major difference between those attributes, they are fairly similar to me and I tend to use those terms synonymously.

I am thankful for everyone who wants to bring light into this darkend room.

Troy

Answer (score 5):

*Tentative* expresses uncertainty, the idea that the results of research are provisional, or that researchers are not confident a conclusion or forecast is correct.

A research conclusion may be expressed with considerable certainty, but readers may be cautioned that there are conditions under which the results may not hold or that the results are valid only for the groups or areas studied. “However” is a word that may introduce such *hedging.*. A researcher may have confidence in a forecast or prediction provided that (for example) vaccines are indeed successful in controlling Covid-19.

One might argue that a great deal of the difference is in the writing.

Answer (score 4):

Tentativeness is a more abstract and general *quality*:

> Done without confidence; hesitant. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tentative)

Whereas hedging is a *technique* that might be used by someone who is tentative:

> Limit or qualify (something) by conditions or exceptions. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hedge)

Although the two tend to go together, one might, for example, be tentative simply by making common or easily-proven claims, without hedging them.  And one might make some claims that are so bold as to seem that they couldn't be called "tentative", but nevertheless still "hedge" those claims by making them conditional or otherwise non-universal.

Comment: This is the best answer so far in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

On the one hand, hedging is taking a restrained position on the possibility that something else might be true - leaving the door open for other possibile conclusions your research might support in the alternative; but on the other hand, tentative is taking a more restrained position than the evidence might support to avoid being seen as sticking one's neck out - hesitant to take a strong opinion, for fear of looking bad or through risk avoidance.

But I might be wrong.

Although I'm pretty sure I disagree with your characterization of hedging as necessarily polite - sometimes it can be weasly.

Comment: +1. I agree that *hedging* carries a negative connotation, whereas tentative does not. In medicine, hedging is a way of "covering [your] ass" (CYA) and is not looked on favorably. Radiologists are notorious for hedging (one doesn't often get a definitive reading, and they usually suggest a repeat or additional study to cover themselves.) This leads to a common joke about the radiology coat of arms depicting a weasel in front of a hedge.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I've been caught out with the negative connotations flowing across from the other subsenses of 'hedge' (see the Wikipedia article), when I'd intended 'considerately wrapped so as not to be offensive'. But 'tentative' carries similar baggage: << tentative ... 
(2) [adjective] 
If someone is tentative, they are cautious and not very confident because they are uncertain or afraid. ... synonyms: ... hesitant ... uncertain ... doubtful ... backward ... faltering 
 ... diffident >> [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tentative)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Connotation is everything, isn't it? I loved my first "real" dictionary (Webster's Collegiate) because it emphasized connotation; I'd flip from one synonym to the next to *get* connotation. (What a nerd!) While you're right, to me, hedging has a hint of dishonesty to it (maybe because of my experience of it) whereas tentative is... careful? A conundrum.

Answer (score 2):

Hedging limits risk.  You might understand "hedging" better in the context of betting, where the word is often used.  For example, if I bet a lot of money on a team to win a baseball game, and later I decide I shouldn't have bet so much, I might bet on the other team to win.  That's called "hedging" a bet.

Insurance is also sometimes referred to as "hedging" - your are limiting your risk.

When you make a statement in such a way as to protect yourself from the risk of being wrong, that's hedging.  For example, adding "I think that..." to the beginning of a sentence or "... but I could be wrong" at the end of it.  A common way that professional advisors hedge is by saying "that should work" instead of "that will work."

As stated above, speaking tentatively *might* involve hedging, but it could also describe other forms of speaking without confidence, like speaking softly.

Comment: I have set answers in order of activity, so the one above yours was posted two hours later. If I set answers according to the number of votes they have received, I see PJB's heading the list followed by yours. Which answer were you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a huge difference in the meaning of the two terms, although *hedge* is also used as a technical term for specific linguistic devices, whereas *tentative* is a more descriptive term for the style of writing. (See the Wikipedia article linked for categories  of hedges with examples.)

**Hedges and politeness**

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth points out:

"Hedges can also be used to politely give commands and requests to others:

> *Could you please shut the window, Phil?*

Wikipedia includes this, but omits it in its introductory overview."

> In the linguistic sub-fields of applied linguistics and pragmatics, a
> **hedge** is a word or phrase used in a sentence to express **ambiguity, probability, caution, or indecisiveness** about the remainder of the
> sentence, rather than full accuracy, certainty, confidence, or
> decisiveness.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics))

> **Tentative language** is particularly used in the writing of academic papers because the purpose of academic papers is questioning what is
> true and why it is true. Tentative language puts forth ideas as ideas,
> rather than offering ideas as definite answers. **Sometimes tentative
> language is called hedging or vague language.** The writers of academic
> papers use **tentative language or hedging** for several reasons:
>
> 1. They downplay their statements in order **to reduce the risk of possible opposition**, especially if their statements, arguments or
>    claims are new and need further verifications.
> 2. One could consider hedges as **ways of being more precise** in reporting results because academic writers may well wish **to reduce the
>    strength of claims** simply because stronger statements would be
>    justified by the data or evidence presented.
> 3. Sometimes they use hedging in order **to appear humble rather than arrogant or all-knowing**.  [B. Klimova; "Using Tentative Language in English" in *Procedia*, Vol. 116](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/277811/1-s2.0-S1877042814X00108/1-s2.0-S1877042814002924/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEGEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCICP3PEVV4p5Le3XRW0Hq%2FTwmrVGpRD4Pw18jpxr92vUxAiEAv1ezvXyFeU%2BEErn%2FxM1mSHQTNOE8Oe9BSnQiwlbrezUq%2BgMIGhAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDGoNqdr0O7GeIfVa5SrXA%2BeTMeKpQisL4zjkZC31At6FlI04%2B5khZiFlQJ2RDIbqHH9Zq2BzULejwkOkgjeJoy0EDyKgOUlptLnbt3PBt%2Bj1YbB1FIZK1aZFob%2F%2Bp9vct%2B0fl70qLmTVq31%2BuMSy9CbyU3EKTBHgCg241zfUcPjaCvv7%2F7kyFaUJyua71Huj%2B5CBOuh0gYR5hUil%2FRbpTj7oqC0IvmnrQbu6Uy3klXCutIwjgiuo8RIrjF8Kjtor5MpiSzKHtOrMHVXBi55Uf0Ud31eV2%2B8E8Y9wsHeFMvgGp3%2F2BCnc8Bgi8X9MlirbaS2qcE1G4SbW9qNHVV%2F5iar%2BAoOlDgOjiuX5%2FzJmQmJRWlUrXRtD9eALoS5vaDmFtkMSyAw%2Fb%2FOe7mYAcMssLcNyQb2rPnc6r8lUs43MSD%2BK5pcW43fUwsPxgF0g5PGX6vfoN8zLsaGGa6v0ru4PXJ17i9mAKUNwOO5RTT4VdZuImoUaavnHqS3S7L53GdaXwmJLzF4z65EgHmTocopm2F8Onm9c3x0gRaX39LGJqvgD%2FeMCaUrXzjsQZmU%2FhUSHl0%2By3Rvec6ednfSvA6DOf5485iugXoFT304ku5DORGeOIkRx7TTohmC4nqOHy0CQ2MtOiUowlzDa9YCTBjqlAdmx48VrOslNMj85dU%2BdkuwzxcZDzr17j8uRbSiBD9BkfXbvjNW%2FcgoLe%2FmUfaecbKzVb2mCXbL5Ahc3nGOrw%2B%2FT%2BBX6Mt9fiYJFM%2FaApRCK%2F%2Bc9euE9ON6w2%2FIcopD42HqzWQrht64Z8T1274RXUgHVnA5iFtwL2nIrEAzfuNfba44ivnIw0vIpshoPVovtFC8qrfk8HC9MHKSEZTfVjoZiDwKzjg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220420T180937Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY5W77S3RY%2F20220420%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=dd84a8210859474d418f6f5e779c070460f05f04c779815669beb6518fe26f5c&hash=4362e3af382ef9912ac82dda680f4006ab781cadb2ea8a83f7190176beeccf11&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S1877042814002924&tid=spdf-bd0c4a21-6c3c-468b-91a8-4068e6960170&sid=08ad64b561d0144dbb18d706cf8a132508b3gxrqa&type=client) (2014)

Hedging is thus not always a "politeness tool" and, as mentioned, is common in the sciences when authors wish to "reduce the strength of claims," as Klimova states. In any case, *care must be taken not to overdo a hedge*. This is a frequent problem when authors who are not fluent in English write for scientific journals, especially in the *Conclusion* section. Such stylistic problems (as well as grammatical errors) used to be corrected before publication, but for many journals those days are long gone. (My own past experience correcting English drafts of Italian scientific papers translated by the authors  is that double and triple hedges don't seem to raise many flags: each hedge in the original gets faithfully translated.)

Examples:

> As for the **potential** benefits of the treatment from data on patients
> without ADs [autoimmune diseases], we may **extrapolate** that there
> **may be** a **possible** effect on large number of patients who develop radiographic progression and reduction of symptomatic days,
> but an additional benefit of the addition of Azithromycin (AZ) to
> therapy is **uncertain**. [T. Georgiev and K. Angelov; "Complexities of
> diagnosis and management of COVID-19 in autoimmune diseases: Potential
> benefits and detriments of immunosuppression" in *World J Clin
> Cases*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7479565/) (2020)

> These results **suggest** that AAS [anabolic-androgenic steroids]
> **could be** a **possible** new risk factor for TAFLD [toxicant-associated fatty liver disease]. [R. Schwingel et al.;
> "Anabolic-androgenic steroids: a possible new risk factor of
> toxicant-associated fatty liver disease" in *Liver International*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1478-3231.2010.02346.x)
> (2010)

Comment: In an overview addressing the whole subject, I'd include << 'Hedges and politeness:
Hedges can also be used to politely give commands and requests to others*.' >> ("Could you please shut the window, Phil?") Wikipedia includes this, but omits it in _its_ introductory overview.  It (when accompanying other listed uses) makes 'Hedging is thus not always a "politeness tool" ' more logical. // * I'd include 'and to downtone tellings off'. "You really ought not to ...."

Comment: Some paraphrases seem intrinsically less incisive /abrupt than others. 'Where are you off to [,Paul]?' seems far friendlier than 'Where are you going [,Paul]?'  'You'd best get going, [then,] miladdo!' is far less trenchant than 'Move it, pilgrim!'

Answer (score 0):

Hedging is an act of using tentative or cautious language. You can make your claims more tentative by hedging. As far as I can tell, there isn't another method of being tentative in academic writing, which may be why it's confusing, since hedging then is the only item in the "tentative methods" subset.

So, be tentative.
Ways of being tentative?

1. Hedging